# Подгрузка и чтение локального XML при помощи JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xml, файловая-система

В настоящий момент, из-за [политики безопасности хромиума](https://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html), нельзя подгружать локальные файлы через ajax без аргумента «--allow-file-access-from-files». Но мне в текущий момент требуется создать веб-приложение, где базой данных является xml-файл (в крайнем случае json), находящийся рядом с index.html. Подразумевается, что пользователь может запустить это приложение локально. Есть ли обходные пути для кроссбраузерного (ie11+) чтения xml-(json-) файла, без оборачивания его в функцию и переименования в формат js?

---

**UPD**

Есть код для IE, но с ним, как оказалось, проблем никаких и не было

```
function loadXMLFile(filename) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        // Если мы имеем дело с IE, то работает с ActiveX-контентом
        if('ActiveXObject' in window) {
            // Получение xml-текста из файла для осла
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.load(filename);

            resolve(xmlDoc.xml);

        } else {

            // Если мы работаем с нормальными браузерами,
            // то здесь необходимо как-то получить xml-файл
            // ...
            // 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Локально то есть веб сервера не будет?

Comment: @heff Нет конечно, иначе бы не было проблемы

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51297/discussion-on-question-by-vasya-shmarovoz-----xml-).

Answer (score 6):

Возможны следующие варианты:

1. Расширение браузера. Оно работает почти как локальные файлы (в том смысле, что файлы статические и лежат в файловой системе) - но для доступа к ресурсам используется не схема `file:///path/to/file`, а схема `chrome-extension:///{guid}/path/to/file`. В этой схеме нет никаких ограничений на доступ к ресурсам вашего же приложения. Все, что вам нужно - составить правильный манифест и упаковать приложение в архив. Ну, и добавить его в браузер, конечно же.

   Вот тут есть полный формат файла манифеста: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest

   Минимальный манифест - вот такой:

   ```
   {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "Мое приложение",
     "version": "1.0",

     "default_locale": "ru",
     "description": "Описание приложения",
     "icons": {
       "16": "icon16.png",
       "48": "icon48.png",
       "128": "icon128.png"
     }
   }
   ```

   Если я ничего не напутал - такого минимального манифеста хватит для того чтобы просто отобразить статические файлы.

   Для того чтобы добавить приложение в хроме - надо опубликовать его в магазине приложений, но для хромиума это не обязательно.
2. Локальный сервер. В сети имеется достаточно легковесных веб-серверов, которые не требуют установки и которые могут отдавать статические файлы по какому-нибудь URL вида `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`.

   Или же, наоборот, можно сделать приложение, которое требует установки и во время этой самой установки поднимает сайт на IIS. Статический сайт поднять не так и сложно, сложнее поставить сам IIS автоматически (это точно возможно, но не помню как).
3. Встроенный браузер. Если встроить хромиум в ваше приложение - можно "подсунуть" ему любые файлы по нестандартной схеме. Или по стандартной - но выставив все нужные флаги.

   Из готовых решений на слуху [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start). Помимо прочих возможностей, Electron позволяет хранимому локально "клиентскому" коду использовать весь API Node.js.

Comment: Благодарю за столь подробный ответ, но к сожалению, он не соответствует сущности вопроса

Comment: Пользователь — обычная Зиннаида Ивановна, владелец какого-нибудь небольшого ООО, где есть своя локальная сеть. Ей только вчера сисадмин рассказал, что есть хорошие браузеры помимо ИЕ. И вот у неё оказалось это SPA на рабочем столе (после того как она через программу создала нужный ей xml с содержимым). И прежде чем отдать его сисадмину, чтобы он загрузил на локальный сервер, она хочет открыть index.html сама, что бы проверить его. Но хром, который она вчера сказала, не подгружает xml, в итоге открывается пустая страница

Comment: В конкретном случае пользователь не должен устанавливать никакое стороннее ПО. Вопрос был создан с целью узнать, существует ли какой-нибудь обходной путь для подгрузки xml, либо нативные способы его подключения локально

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz а откуда у Зиннаиды Ивановны на рабочем столе взялся index.html? И откуда у нее взялась программа, которая этот xml генерирует?

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz если программа для генерации - ваша, то вот и то самое стороннее ПО. А если нет - то отбираем у Зиннаиды index.html и говорим загружать файл на сайт для проверки.

Comment: подготовленный архив с index.html, скриптами, стилями и сгенерированным xml-файлов выдала программа. Программа для генерации наша, но она уже неактуальна, делалась давно и на c++. Сейчас в штате сишника нет, а программа до сих пор поставляется. Сейчас идёт подготовительный этап создания её веб-версии. Пока веб-версии нет, люди пользуются десктопной. Это отдельный и долгий разговор

Comment: мы не можем ничего отбирать у неё, ничего давать ей и т.д. В текущей задаче у нас есть xml-файл (который мы можем завернуть в другой формат при писав какие-то данные), есть его визуализатор. Если были возможны другие пути решения проблемы, такие как запуск локалхоста, создания плагинов для разных браузеров, использования node.js или других платформ..., вопроса бы не было

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz значит, надо сделать веб-сайт, куда Зиннаида отправит архив целиком на предпросмотр. Посмотрите на dropzone.js - там реализовано красивое перетаскивание мышкой файлов прямо в окно браузера.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz а на сайте развернете архив во временную папку и покажете результат. Сразу после того как файл будет перетащен.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz как вариант - то же самое, но вместо сайта расширение к хромиуму.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz в целом же ситуация дурацкая. *"Вы нам сделайте программу, только мы ее ставить не будем"*. Так не бывает.

Comment: Павел, суть вопроса была в попытке найти способ подгрузки xml-файла локально, и всё. Сейчас абсолютно ясно, что политика безопасности хромиума не позволяет получать доступ к контенту никоим образом. Поэтому сейчас всё оборачивается в .js-файл и работает. Все эти клоуны с вертолётами, что вы предлагаете, абсолютно не подходят для для пустяковой, по сути, задачи. То что ситуация дурацкая — отрицать не буду, до ужаса дурацкая, но тут поделать ничего нельзя

Comment: Вам с самого начала это твердили, неужели так трудно было это понять.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz, если нужно только визуализировать xml - то можно попробовать xslt

Comment: @Grundy не получится, локальные файлы считаются полученными из разных доменов

Comment: @VladimirGamalian пять лет назад работало :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov лет пять назад и проблемы такой не было)